# Configure firebase to use java package instead of application ID

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two apps that use this same id, one is android mobile, on android tv. They need to have this same id, because of google play store, so I can not give them a different application ID on firebase.

Is there some way that firebase can be configured to use java package instead of applicationId from build.gradle?

Or is there another way to solve this, without changing applicationID in build.gradle?

Comment: Are you saying that you can't just use the same Firebase configuration for both apps?  If they are the same app with the same underlying data in Firebase, they should have the same configuration.

Comment: Actually now, let's just say that i am not author of second app and i need to see separete events on firebase :(

Comment: so you have one app which is coded for both android mobile and tv but the events have to be logged separately?

Comment: Nope i have two apps, mobile app is app that was not developed by me, but my app and mobile app have to use same applicationId for Google Play store. So on playstore there is only one app, and based on device (mobile or tv) either not mine mobile device is installed or mine tv app is installed. Which is problem for firebase because i can now see events from both apps (because they have same applicationId)

Answer (score 0):

Try this format:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok so i found out that i can use FirebaseApp and create new instance of FirebaseApp(Context c, FirebaseOption.FromResource, String s) where last string is package name (custom one) which will be the same as in google-service.json file i can generate from firebase console. But now problem is that i can not connect firebase app object with firebaseAnalytics objects which have method for sending logged events logEvent(). Anyone knows how i can connect those two things?